# Handling Android Locale

Tags: android, kotlin

I was struggling with date formatting in Kotlin.

Does someone know why using :

```kotlin
val locale = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().configuration).get(0)
java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(java.text.DateFormat.SHORT, locale).format(Date())
```

give me :

- In FR_fr = 08/09/2022 (expected)
- In EN_gb = 08/09/2022 (unexpected)

BUT

```kotlin
val currentLanguage = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().configuration).get(0).language
val locale = Locale(currentLanguage)
java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(java.text.DateFormat.SHORT, locale).format(Date())
```

gives me :

- In FR_fr = 08/09/2022 (expected)
- In EN_gb = 9/8/2022 (expected)

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second one, while you are doing this,

> ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().configuration).get(0).language

it will give language as `en`.It will not give country variant english.It will return generic english locale.

So you should create locale like below.

```
  val currentLanguage = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().configuration).get(0)
        if (currentLanguage!=null) {
            val currentLocale = Locale(currentLanguage.language, currentLanguage.country, currentLanguage.variant)
        }
```

THis will create locale with en-GB in your case.

In the first one you are already getting locale object with `en-GB`.

`en-GB` and `en` has different formats of date.

```
08/09/2022 : en-GB
9/8/2022 : en
```

`en-IN` (Indian English) also will give `08/09/2022` as result.

Comment: That's very clear ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the different results is because

- in you first example, you work with actual `en_GB`/`fr_FR` locale,
- but in the second example, your locale is only `en`/ `fr`.
  That's because `language`/`getLanguage()` in this instance returns only `en`/ `fr`, without country specification.

So, I'd say, the first result (`08/09/2022`) is the correct one for `en_GB`. If you want a different date format you probably have to create your own one.

Comment: Okay but I don't understand why the date format is different when I use `ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().configuration).get(0)` (on an device set in English) and `Locale.ENGLISH`.

Comment: The first gives either `en_US`, `en_GB`, `en_AU`, etc. `US` uses different date formats than `GB`. That's why the country is as important as the language. `Locale.ENGLISH` can only make a guess what date format is desired, as the country isn't specified. The date format is not only dependent on the language but also the location.